# CSS3 breaking when element value is empty

Tags: html, css

Below is my code snippet, my problem was whenever am getting empty or null values for the items. 
Say **itemDescription** value is Empty, so everything moves one up and breaks the whole page

```
    <span class="itemDetails">
         <li class="items"><%=itemDescription%></li>
        <li class="items"><%= itemNumber || item.rTagID %></li>
        <li class="items"><%=itemBayId%></li>
        <li class="items"><%=itemAmnt%></li>
    </span>
```

**CSS Code**

```
    .itemDetails {
       display: inline-block;
     }
    .items{
       display: table-row;
     }
```

Am I doing anything basically wrong, or just missing a link here?

Comment: That I think is the default behavior of `li` elements. There is a work-around possible using CSS3. Would you be interested in that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `min-height` property (check for ref: http://caniuse.com/#feat=minmaxwh) you have to use display block for list items to work with `min-height` properly.

```
<style type="text/css">
 .itemDetails {
       display: inline-block;
     }
    .items{
        border:1px solid red;
       display: block;
       min-height:40px;
     }


</style>
<ul class="itemDetails">
    <li class="items">abcde</li>
    <li class="items"></li>
    <li class="items">lmnop</li>
    <li class="items">qrstuv</li>
    <li class="items">wxyz</li>
    <li class="items">abcde</li>
    <li class="items">fghijk</li>
    <li class="items">lmnop</li>
    <li class="items">qrstuv</li>
    <li class="items">wxyz</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `li` elements without `ul` parent , try this

```
<ul class="itemDetails">
         <li><%=itemDescription%></li>
        <li><%= itemNumber || item.rTagID %></li>
        <li><%=itemBayId%></li>
        <li><%=itemAmnt%></li>
 </ul>

ul.itemDetails {
       display: inline-block;
     }
ul.itemDetails li{
       display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: add the parent or full html code maybe the problem appear from another element